# Can any debugger trace the value passing at all?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Debugger like GDB can stop the program at where some address is being written or read, by using watchpoints. I wonder, is there a debugger that can trace the whole effect of a value read from some address specified, which means, recording the history from where it was read to where it was copied to, and where that copy is read and copied to and so on ? Please point out my nonsense as a new bee.

a debugger background or some random guy who know computer.

Comment: _valgrind_ does something like this, tracking invalid memory accesses.